# Find Material that are assigned to more than one category

Tags: sql, sql-server

What would be the query to find List of material that are assigned to more than one maincode.

Here is the sample data

```
CREATE TABLE #MaterialMainCodetemp (
    MaterialCode VARCHAR(100),
    Maincode varchar(100)
);
Insert into #MaterialMainCodetemp Values('Material1','Main1')
Insert into #MaterialMainCodetemp Values('Material5','Main1')
Insert into #MaterialMainCodetemp Values('Material2','Main1')
Insert into #MaterialMainCodetemp Values('Material3','Main1')
Insert into #MaterialMainCodetemp Values('Material4','Main1')
Insert into #MaterialMainCodetemp Values('Material1','Main2')
Insert into #MaterialMainCodetemp Values('Material6','Main2')
Insert into #MaterialMainCodetemp Values('Material7','Main2')
Insert into #MaterialMainCodetemp Values('Material8','Main3')
Insert into #MaterialMainCodetemp Values('Material4','Main4')


Select M.MaterialCode,Count(*) from #MaterialMainCodetemp M
GROUP By M.MaterialCode
Having Count(*) > 1
```

Above query Returns this, but i should only get back Material1, since only that material is assign two different MainCode

```
MaterialCode    (No column name)
Material4          2
Material1          2
```

What Query would look like that will return Material1 only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your sample data is off.  Material4 is in fact assigned two different main codes.  Change your last insert statement to:

```
Insert into #MaterialMainCodetemp Values('Material4','Main1')
```

or drop it entirely.

However, your query would still give you that result even if you changed it. So use `count(distinct maincode)`:

```
Select M.MaterialCode,Count(distinct maincode) from #MaterialMainCodetemp M
GROUP By M.MaterialCode
Having Count(distinct maincode) > 1
```